# iterating over arrays in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to pass an array into a MySQL query and return the results as another array ?(apart from using cursors which would be an overkill for my use case)

For a single id, my query looks like this.

```
SET @userId = '04b452cd59dcc656'
Select user_account_number from userstore where u_id = @userId ;
```

Instead of sending each id at a time, I am trying to send a list and return a list

```
SET @userId = ('04b452cd59dcc656','eqwe52cddasfsd656');
<query returning the list of account numbers>
```

Also - I think this would be efficient over just sending one id at a time. Thoughts ?

Comment: Mysql does not implement any arrays. You can use string concatenation to dynamically create sql statements and to create concatenated, comma delimited output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IN`:

```
select user_account_number
from userstore
where u_id in ('04b452cd59dcc656', 'eqwe52cddasfsd656') ;
```

Using variables is trickier.  If you know a maximum number, you can do:

```
select user_account_number
from userstore
where u_id in (@id1, @id2);
```

Not satisfying, but it does the job.  Similarly unsatisfying is `FIND_IN_SET()`:

```
set @ids = '04b452cd59dcc656,eqwe52cddasfsd656';

select user_account_number
from userstore
where find_in_set(u_id, @ids) > 0;
```

Alas, this won't use an index.

Finally there is dynamic SQL:

```
set @sql = concat('select user_account_number from userstore where u_id in (''',
                  replace(ids, ',', ''','''),
                  ''')'
                 );

prepare s from @sql;
execute s;
```

Comment: Thanks. The first two does not work as the length of the array is not fixed and is not known to me before hand. 

The third one works. But , why do you call it 'not satisfying' ?And also did not follow your comment FIND_IN_SET is 'similarly unsatisfying'. Similarly unsatisfying to what ? I don't see anything else in that query that can be unsatisfying. :O

Comment: @user5566364 . . . Having to use dynamic SQL to solve this problem is a sad reality of the SQL language.